# Exception not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello i have a string which is loaded from json to a function , the function executes this string using eval , but i am getting some error with % modulo  operator which need to perform modulo operation can any one help me with it

`"((column['salary']%100)<3,(column['salary']%1000)<4,(column['salary']%10000)<5)"`

in the function the column gets replaced to df

`"((df['salary']%100)<3,(df['salary']%1000)<4,(df['salary']%10000)<5)"​`

`eval("((df['salary']%100)<3,(df['salary']%1000)<4,(df['salary']%10000)<5)")`

and eval of string gives error
`Exception not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python`

and the data frame is in  below pic

[image]

Comment: Please add an excerpt of your dataframe so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: bailey any answer for this

Comment: Please add your dataframe as a code block so it can be copied, and so it is readable for people who use screen readers. You can see how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).